# How can I use a look-up table for the column names of a table in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table for example

[image]

I need to create a lookup table that references the column names of this table. (Column names are unique) Eg. SNo is SerialNumberOfChinaAsia etc and I want to store this new name as a primary key in another table and refer the old name SNo as a foreign key using SQlite3. How can such a lookup table be created?

Originally I have a table with 300 columns and the big column names do not fit in the query during table creation.

Comment: If you want to call `SNo` something like `SerialNumberOfChinaAsia`, then I would suggest that you use views.

Comment: Trying to dynamically generate and access columns is a good indicator that your schema is flawed. Instead of having a bunch of `SerialNumberOf$COUNTRY` columns, you should have two columns `SerialNumber` and `Country` and one row for each country+serial number pair.